# Server keeps crashing due to high RAM usage - realtime IP monitoring?

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, centos, awstats

Is there a way to monitor realtime IP traffic coming into my server and seeing how much bandwith and RAM is being used?

Every once in a while it seems like I get a DOS type of attack where my website becomes unresponsive, and I can't do anthing until I request a hard re-boot from my hosting company.  I would like to be able to see which IP addresses are currently listed on my server at the time the server becomes unresponsive due to exhausted RAM usage this way I can block these IPs from accessing my website again in the future.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of tools that you can use:

1. Command line tools: [iptraf](http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/10/04/monitoring-linux-bandwidth-utilization-with-iptraf-and-iftop/), [iftop](http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/10/04/monitoring-linux-bandwidth-utilization-with-iptraf-and-iftop/), [jnettop](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/?id=Screenshots)
2. Web interface tools [Ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/)(It runs as a Daemon and you can see a lot of graphs and summaries about all traffic in your server)
3. The old [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/download/) (Good and Robust but you may need some time to familiarize yourself with)

You can find here a good article on best monitoring tools in the Unix/Linux world : [Linux performance monitoring tools](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/linux-performance-monitoring-tools/).